# Android UI getting stretched widthwise

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio-3.0, android-8.1-oreo

I have a custom display [stretched widthwise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bvcv.jpg) with 1920x720 resolution, screensize 10.3 inch with aspect ratio 8:3.I am using the android presentation class for this screen.While using presentation class android screen UI will be fit to the display by default without any bottom or top bars(not even home or back buttons)ie the whole screen will be filled with the application UI. How to make UI for this resolutions and aspect ratios? why my images getting stretched widthwise in my application UI?

Comment: you should make sure to choose a display resolution and picture size that matches your phone screen aspect ratio ! as you can notice 1920/720 doesn't match with 8/3 , that's why your pictures getting stretched.

Answer (score 0):

For full width or full height images you have to dynamically change the size of the imageView like this :-

1. You need to know the ratio of the original image.
2. Then calculate the width of your screen using this code:-

***see the code below :***

```
    public static int getScreenWidth(Context mContext) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((Activity) 
     mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            return metrics.widthPixels;
        }
```

3.Now you have to change the params of imageView like this:-

```
 imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (Utility.getScreenWidth(this) * "your ratio");
```

Hope this helps.